# Sharing a Document with UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I'm trying to share a document stored in the temporary directory using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Essentially, I'm using the following code:

```
@IBAction func createDocumentButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        // create temporary file
        let tempUrl = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("fileName.txt")
        try "abc".write(to: tempUrl, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

        // share file
        let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempUrl)
        documentInteractionController!.name = "filename.txt"
        documentInteractionController!.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
    } catch {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When run, this code presents the share action sheet. The log indicates some problem: `Could not instantiate class NSURL. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "The URL archive of type “public.url” contains invalid data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The URL archive of type “public.url” contains invalid data.`
Selecting any of the options results in failure handling the document.

This is reduced to pretty much textbook level code, yet it is not working. What am I missing?

**Update:**
Added context that better emphasizes the cause of the problem (see my answer below).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turned out to be trivial, even silly. I leave the question anyhow in case someone else stumbles over it.

I need to maintain the instance of `UIDocumentInteractionController` outside the button action handler that presents the controller. I will update the question to better show this problem. With a small change, it works as expected:

```
var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController?

@IBAction func createDocumentButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        // create temporary file
        let tempUrl = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("fileName.txt")
        try "abc".write(to: tempUrl, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

        // share file
        documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempUrl)
        documentInteractionController!.name = "filename.txt"
        documentInteractionController!.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
    } catch {
        // ...
    }
}
```